# log4j on jboss - subpackage level

Tags: log4j

I have JBoss 6.1 and using jboss-logging.xml
I would like to set different log level for one package, and one his subpackage, example:
- com.foo.bar (in DEBUG)
- com.foo.bar.subpack.subsubpack (in INFO)
I have tried with this:

```
<logger category="com.foo.bar">
 <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
<logger category="com.foo.bar.subpack">
 <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

But in the log I continue to see all the debug message from the class in the subpack

Comment: Your configuration looks ok. Did you try to set "INFO level for com.foo.bar package ? Maybe your are configuring the wrong file... ?

Comment: The file is right, cause I have change the console level from INFO to DEBUG and now I see all the DEBUG mess.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the messages are readen twice by the loggers. Disable additivity :

```
<logger category="com.foo.bar" additivity="false">
 <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
<logger category="com.foo.bar.subpack">
 <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

Edit :

Otherwise, check the name by whitch your are instanciating your logger.

According to https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Logger_hierarchy, if you write `Logger.getLogger("PIPPO")`, and if the logger with name "PIPPO" does not exist in your configuration(s) file(s), the RootLogger will be instanciated by default.

> A logger is said to be an ancestor of another logger if its name followed by a dot is a prefix of the descendant logger name. A logger is said to be a parent of a child logger if there are no ancestors between itself and the descendant logger.

To apply your configuration, you have to instanciate the logger by calling it with a name like "com.foo.bar.subpack.YourClass".

Comment: The message are not in twice, but single, and this solution (additivity = false) dont change the situation.

Comment: Inspecting the code I see that the logger constuctor is Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("PIPPO"); and not the usual Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()); Maybe it is a problem.

Comment: OK, I'm editing my answer for anyone with the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem: using the constructor Logger.getLogger("PIPPO"), in the xml the category is "PIPPO":

```
<logger category="PIPPO">
   <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

This tag control the level message  of the class